# Joins using Pyspark(Python) in databricks not working

Tags: azure, databricks, pyspark

Inner join using Pyspark not working with dataframes created using partitioned csv , regular csv and SQL table.

Eg: When I try to apply inner join on the dataframe created using Partitioned csv(stored in ADLS) and normal csv, the output df is creating with blank values but when I do join on dataframes created on regular csvs it is working fine.

Is there any restriction in databricks for that?

Comment: Could you please provide more details which you have tried like (sample tried, any error message received) ?

Comment: Meanwhile, you can checkout Pyspark Joins by examples: http://www.learnbymarketing.com/1100/pyspark-joins-by-example/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys. Came to know that there is an issue with the DF schema. which we corrected and it worked.